# Visualize ThreadPool

Tags: .net, multithreading, visual-studio, threadpool

I am using ThreadPool with `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.

Now I am looking for a possibility to look into the ThreadPool while Debugging. Is there a way to do this in Visual Studio?

Comment: I would advice against using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` and use `Task.Run` instead. It does the same thing of putting work on the pool but because it has a Task wrapper you can watch its progress on the Tasks tab of the debugger.

Comment: Use Debug > Windows > Threads to keep track of running threads.